# Viewing local saved HTML5 and javascript in ios14

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios

I know very little about HTML5 and Javascript, however what i have used to work on ios13. The background is that i have a Python script that analyzes a dataset and then writes an html file to save as a report. The HTML file contains the Javascript and CSS rather than referencing external .js and .css files. The images are encoded as base64 to allow them to be embedded in the HTML.  This allows one single file that can be saved, emailed etc.

Prior to ios14 when someone emailed me the output html i could open it on my iphone and open the various sections (uses javascript). However since ios14 i can longer get the sections to open so assume that ios14 is blocking the javascript from working in an html preview.  If i put one of these HTML files onto a webserver and navigate to them via Safari, then the javascript works fine.  Below is javascript used, i took the function from W3C schools examples IRC.

```
<script>
<var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}

function changeImage(element) {
  document.getElementById('imageReplace').src = element;
}
    </script>
```

The CSS used for the collapsible sections is:

```
.collapsible {

    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
}
  
.collapsible:hover {
    background-color: #45484b;
    
}
  
.collapsible:after {
    content: '\002B';
    float: right;
}
  
.active:after {
    content: "\2212";
}
  
.content {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
 }
```

The individual collapsible sections are created using the following html:

```
<section id="section_name">
    <h2 class="collapsible">Section Header</h2>
        <div class="content">
All HTML that i want to appear and disappear by clicking on H2
        </div>
</section>
```

I dont have an Apple developer account so am not sure if there were any security changes in ios14 and what the workaround would be.

Comment: When you say you used to be able to open 'it' on your phone, do you mean you could see the email's content fully in your email client or are you using something else to view it?

Comment: Sorry about the super late reply. Yes the issue was that prior to ios 14 when i received the HTML file as an email attachment i could click on it and and the javascript would work in that i could click on the various H2 headers and the javascript would open the collapsible section. In ios14 i can still open the HTML attachment but the javascript doesn't appear to be allowed to run, i click on the H2 headers but the section isn't opened.